# Trying to populate an array with random 32-bit binary numbers

Tags: c, arrays, random, binary

I have an assignment to program the game of life in Standard C. I am only allowed to use 1D arrays. My first issue is trying to get my array populated with random 32 bit binary digits. I have tried making code to do this (with code supplied by my teacher which is not commented at all, so I have to some extent no idea what I am doing). When I try displaying the contents of the array it seems that at every index the values are all the same. Can you guys help me populate my array with 32 random binary digits (32 bits in length).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARSZ 32 

void displayBinary(unsigned long* , int);
unsigned long init32();

unsigned long Row[ARSZ];

int main(void){

    int i, j;

    for (i=0;i<ARSZ;i++){
        Row[i] = init32();
    }//populate array

    for (j=0;j<ARSZ;j++){
        displayBinary(Row, j);
        printf("\n");
    }//display array contents
}/** End Main **/


void displayBinary(unsigned long array[], int x){

    unsigned long MASK = 0x80000000;
    do {
        printf("%c", (array[x] & MASK) ?'X':0x20);
    }while ((MASK >>=1) != 0);
}

unsigned long init32(){

    unsigned long init32;
    srand(time(NULL));  
    init32 = ((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*0xFFFFFFFF;
    return init32;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're already populating it, are you looking for an explanation of the code?

Comment: Take that [`srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) call **out** of your function and invoke it **once** at the top of `main()`. That function should never be called more than once per process-run unless you *seriously* know what you're doing.

Comment: It's fine to call `srand()` multiple times, however if `init32` is called more than once a second the seed may be the same value (when using `time(NULL)`) giving you the same sequence of numbers. In this case it will be called multiple times a second and give you repeated values.

Comment: @CairnO. Unless you're *specifically* using `srand()` for seeding to generate a *specific* sequence from the generator, calling it "multiple times" utterly defeats the purpose of the algorithm behind the generator and its period recurrence. The more it is done the more the RNG is linked to the seeding sequence, which is outright *wrong*. As I said, unless you seriously know what you're doing `srand()` should be invoked *once* per process.

Comment: I should also mention one other thing. Check the value of `RAND_MAX` on your implementation. If you're on a Visual Studio C++ rig i don't think you're going to like what you find. (Last I checked it was 0x7FFF, which is clearly a major bummer if you're trying to generate something larger than 15 bits, and you are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the seed. The srand(time(NULL)) call is going to return the same sequence of values because the seed hasn't changed.

Take a cursory glance at how the pseudo-random number generator works in C and it'll make sense.

Answer (score 0):

1) Repetitive calling of `srand(time(NULL))`.  Rather than calling `srand()` in `init32()`, call it once in `main()`.  @WhozCraig, @Albert Myers

2) Potentially too small RAND_MAX with `init32 = ((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*0xFFFFFFFF;`.  C only requires `RAND_MAX` to be at least 32767.  This would give `init32` at most 32768 different values.  To certainly generate a 32-bit random number, use:

```
unsigned long init32;
init32 = rand();
init32 <<= 15;
init32 ^= rand();
init32 <<= 15;
init32 ^= rand();
// if pedantic
init32 &= 0xFFFFFFFFL;
```

Note:
A small bias in 32-bit number generation occurs if `RAND_MAX + 1` is not a power-of-2.
Also, `rand()` itself is sometimes nor the uniformly random - depends on platform.

Comment: It works now. I just had to stop the repetitive time call like you said.